# I am building a blog, my issue is whenever i try to update a post it gives a backend error that says id not found. I am using expressjs and mongo db

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, post, put

```
app.put('/post/:id', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let newPath = null;

    if (req.file) {
      const { originalname, path } = req.file;
      const parts = originalname.split('.');
      const ext = parts[parts.length - 1];
      newPath = path + '.' + ext;
      await fs.promises.rename(path, newPath);
    }

    const { token } = req.cookies;
    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      const {id} = req.params;
      const { cat, title, summary, content } = req.body;
      const postDoc = await Post.findById(id);
      const isAuthor = postDoc.author === info.id;
      if (!isAuthor) {
        return res.status(400).json('You are not the author');
      }

      const updatedFields = {
        title,
        cat,
        summary,
        content,
      };

      if (newPath) {
        updatedFields.cover = newPath;
      }

      const updatedPost = await postDoc.findByIdAndUpdate(
        id,
        updatedFields,
        { new: true }
      );

      res.json(updatedPost);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console. Error('Error updating post:', error);
    res.status(500).json('An error occurred while updating the post');
  } enter code here
});
```

this code checks if the user attempting to edit the post is the author, then updates if positive but it is telling me the post isn't found, the console log shows that the frontend gets the post with its id.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try adding a breakpoint in the route and seeing a) what is being read for req.params and b) what query is being sent to Mongo?